# How do you change state of a react component from a different component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand how to pass props to components in react. I am new to react and I have been struggling to understand the fundamentals of state.

I would like a button to display an overlay and populate the "content" of that overlay with some arbitrary text for now.

I am trying to use a prop called doWeDisplay as variable to hold a css value of "none" or "absolute" (to hide and show the component) and a prop called "content" for the content of the overlay.

Here is my code, could someone please point me in the right direction. I need that eureka moment for it to click in place and my head is all over the place trying to get this.

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Overlay from './components/overlay';
import Header from './components/header';
import Body from './components/body';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("App props", this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Overlay />
        <Header />
        <Body content={ this.props.appContent } />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**body.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './body.css';
import Overlay from './overlay'

class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doWeDisplay : "absolute",
      content : "Go on"
    };
  }

  render() {
    function handleClick(e) {
      console.log("Click")
      Overlay.setState((state, props) => ({
        doWeDisplay : "absolute",
        content : "Go on"
      }))
    }
    console.log("Body props ", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="App-Body">
        <p>Here is the body of the page.</p>
        <button onClick={ handleClick }>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Body
```

**overlay.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './overlay.css';

class Overlay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doWeDisplay : props.doWeDisplay,
      content : props.doWeDisplay
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Overlay props " , this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App-Overlay" style={{ display: this.state.doWeDisplay }}>
        { this.state.content }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have sibling components that can change other's state, you will need to handle that state in the parent component (in your case it is `App`).

So the `handleClick()` function should be in the parent component, and the state itself of the variables `doWeDisplay` and `content` should be in `App` as well.

Then, you can pass that function to `Body` as a prop, so you could trigger it on click within the `Body` component. I called that prop `clickFunc` in my example.

Finally, the last thing you will need is to pass the current state to `Overlay` as props, so I passed the `doWeDisplay` and `content` as different props, that gets the value from `App`'s state.

It should look something like this:

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Overlay from './components/overlay';
import Header from './components/header';
import Body from './components/body';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import './App.css';

    class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doWeDisplay: "absolute",
      content: "Go on"
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Click");
    this.setState({
      doWeDisplay: "absolute",
      content: "Go on CHANGED!"
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("App props", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Overlay
          doWeDisplay={this.state.doWeDisplay}
          content={this.state.content}
        />
        <Body clickFunc={this.handleClick} content={this.props.appContent} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**body.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './body.css';
import Overlay from './overlay'

class Body extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Body props ", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="App-Body">
        <p>Here is the body of the page.</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.clickFunc()}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Body
```

**overlay.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './overlay.css';

class Overlay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Overlay props ", this.props);
    return (
      <div className="App-Overlay" style={{ display: this.props.doWeDisplay }}>
        {this.props.content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay
```

Here's [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-joliot-0jup0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Where the handleClick() function is seems to be a problem. Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)

Comment: Oh sry.. umm.. try to omit the "function" word (edited).

Comment: Damn! :)  It's now. Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
  Line 31:28:  'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef (thanks for your help btw)